# How to change company name in "share your information" for auto-renewable subscriptions in iTunes?

Tags: ios, ipad, subscriptions

We've created some auto-renewable subscriptions in iTunes. Typically there is dialog screen "Share your information" coming right after the actually purchase. In this screen the name of the developer/company is mentioned. See image of a similar case:

[image: Share information dialog]

We'd like to be able to change this name (in the example: "the publisher of HD AD"), as it mentions our name (as owner of the itunes developer account) instead of the name of our customer for whom we're creating this app.

Does anyone know how we can change this name ? Which field in iTunes is taken for this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Gilles

Comment: Not a programming question (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Raoul The question could be rephrased as "What Cocoa touch API is available to change the publisher name for subscriptions", so this _is_ a programming question.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington most off topic posts could be rephrased to make them seem like programming questions, this doesn't actually make them programming questions of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You should publish the app using an account owned by (and named after) your customer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can change this value. Under iTunes Connect, navigate to your In-App purchase and click on the details under the Language, Display Name, etc.

The value you need to add, or update, is 'Publication Name' - whatever is in here will appear on the "Share Your Information?" popup.